# Injective function $\left\{3x^2+mx+n\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\left\{3x^2+mx+n\right\}$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{R}$. Function $f$ is injective if

A: $m=-7$

B: $m=0$

C: $m=2$

D: $m=2\cdot 3^{1/3}$

E: $m=4 , 9$

I put the condition for the function $f$ to be injective and got that
$x^2+3mx-y^2-3my=[x^2+3mx]-[y^2+3my]$ but I do not what to do with the integer parts.

Answer (score 1):

By injectivity, for $x,y\in\Bbb Q, \{3x^2+mx+n\}=\{3y^2+my+n\}\iff x=y.$ That is, $(3x+3y+m)(x-y)\in \Bbb Z\iff x-y=0.$ Then $3(x+y)+m\notin\Bbb Z$ for any $x,y\in \Bbb Q$. If $m\in\Bbb Q$, then we may take $x=-\dfrac m3,y=0$ to get $3(x+y)+m=0\in\Bbb Q$, contradiction. Therefore, m must be irrational. Although, I don't think it is possible to give a fixed value (or a finite set of fixed values) as an answer to this problem, since there are not enough info available.

EDIT: When I posted this answer, the question has been edited by other users to not include a crucial part of the problem (the fractional part notation was removed), or the OP simply made a gross mistake while typing in their question. For this reason, this answer is not fitting for the  question currently, as the question has since been edited.

EDIT: I have edited the answer accordingly now, so it fits the question in its current form now (provided the question hasn't been edited again to be a different question)

Comment: You forgot about the integer parts

Comment: @iuli23 There's no need for the consideration of integer parts in your original problem.

Comment: @Gary  I am sorry but the person who edited my question deleted the pharantesis for the fractional part

Comment: @Divide1918 I am sorry but the person who edited my question deleted the pharantesis for the fractional part

Comment: @iuli23 I've edited the answer according to the edit of your question now.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer while the question statement does not reflect what the OP intends to ask and hence deems my original answer unfitting: I've edited the answer so that it fits with the question as the OP intended. Please re-read my answer and consider reverting or keeping the downvote. Thank you.